# How to get specific columns with one to many relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have 3 tables , one to many relationship.

I need to get only specific columns with SelectMany method.

I need to get only Categories.CategoryName and Comments.CommentDate of the selected News object.

Here is my code

```
News news = db.News.Include(w => w.Categories)
                   .Include(w => w.Comments).SingleOrDefault(n => n.NewsId == Id);
```

Here are my Entities:

News Entity:

```
public partial class News
{
    public News()
    {
        this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
        this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    }

    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
    public string NewsBody { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }
    public string NewsImagePath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Category Entity:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.News = new HashSet<News>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Comment Entity:

```
public partial class Comment
{
    public Comment()
    {
        this.News = new HashSet<News>();
    }

    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentBody { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CommentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This LINQ query should take care of it:

```
var query =
    from news in db.News
    where news.Id == Id
    let categoryNames =
        from category in news.Categories
        select category.Name
    let commentDates =
        from comment in news.Comments
        select comment.CommentDate
    select new {
        CategoryNames = categoryNames.ToList(),
        CommentDates = commentDates.ToList()
    };
```

That query is not using `SelectMany`, but that wouldn't help you, since then you wouldn't be able to group your categories and comments by news items. Since categories and comments are not directly connected, you'd need two `SelectMany`s and then you'd need to cross join the results. That would obviously not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the following?

```
var categoryNames = news.Categories.Select(c=>c.CategoryName);
var commentDates = news.Comments.Select(c=>c.CommentDate);
```

Note that `SelectMany` is used to flatten lists.For example, lets say you have collection of news matching certain search criteria, and then you use `SelectMany` to collect all the `Categories`/`Comments` of these news set, in a flat list.

Comment: I don't see how this will solve the problem of the question. It will require two requests to the database and it there is no filter on news Id.

Comment: @Sefe I think you have missed the very first code block in the question. `news` is already filtered with `Id`.

Comment: I stand corrected. You will need actually **three** queries to the DB. I still don't see how this is a viable alternative to a SelectMany query, which would need only one request.

Comment: @Sefe First of all, the `.Include()`s will eagerly load the navigational properties resulting in `join`s, and finally the query is evaluated/executed with `SingleOrDefault` call. So with that the `news` object is now in memory with the `Include`ed paths. So selecting the primitive properties from those collections will be querying against the memory. So trip to database is technically 1.

Comment: @Sefe Having said that, the one upvote you have for your answer is mine, as think it is quite concise. So I think you don't have to put any other extra effort to make the OP accept your answer. Chill :)

Comment: I'm good. In EF the number if requests to the DB matters, so I wanted to mention that. So no offense intended.

Comment: @Sefe none taken :)